# Scrapy - Item returned to pipeline is None when using TakeFirst output processor

Tags: python, scrapy

Basically what the title says. I'm using Python 2.7.9 with Scrapy 0.24.5 on Windows 8.1.

I introduced the TakeFirst output processor in order to get single values in my database rather than a single item list object. When the output processor is used, the Item object received by the Pipeline is None. If I take out the output processor, the Item object contains single value lists and writes them correctly to my database.

I have absolutely no idea why this happens... Below are the relevant code excerpts:

- The parse function of the spider
- The pipeline
- Debugger output of the Item values with and without the output processor
- Data model as per @Lawrence's request

The parse function in my spider looks like this:

```
def parse(self, response):

    chosen_selector = response.xpath("//article[contains(@class, 'someResults')]")

    for props in chosen_selector:
        loader = ItemLoader(MyItem(), selector=props)
        loader.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()  # <<< this causes a problem, unless commented out
        loader.add_xpath('address_raw',
                         ".//a[@class='someLocation']/text()")
        loader.add_xpath(....)
        ....
        yield loader.load_item()
```

My Pipeline which writes the Item to the database looks like this:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    session = self.Session()
    raw_data = Raw_data(**item)
    try:
        session.add(raw_data)
        session.commit()

    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise

    finally:
        session.close()

    return item
```

I set breakpoints in scrapy's ItemLoader class to check the Item with and without the output processor.

Item after it's sent to pipeline without TakeFirst output processor; it's a single value list for each item

```
{
'address_raw': [u'some location'],
 'agent_source': ['example.com'],
 'bathrooms': [u'4'],
 'bedrooms': [u'4'],
 'carparks': [u'4'],
 'company': [u'some company'],
 'datetime_parsed': [datetime.datetime(....)],
 'extract_results': [u'<article ....>......</span></a></div></div></div></article>'],
 ....
 'link_property': [u'some/link'],
 'link_search': ['some/source'],
 'page_number': ['9999'],
 'price_high': 9999,
 'price_raw': [u'$9999 per unit']
 }
```

Item before it is send to pipeline using TakeFirst as the output processor showing that the TakeFirst output processor seems to work; this is None once it arrived at the pipeline above.

```
 {
 'address_raw': u'some location',
 'agent_source': 'example.com',
 'bathrooms': u'4',
 'bedrooms': u'4',
 'carparks': u'4',
 'company': u'some company',
 'extract_results': u'<article ....>......</span></a></div></div></article>',
 ....
 'link_property': u'some/link',
 'link_search': 'some/source',
 'page_number': '9999',
 'price_raw': u'Offers Around $999'
 }
```

Data model

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime

import settings

DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()

....

class Raw_data(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "raw_data"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    address_raw = Column("address_raw", String)
    ...  # all other columns, as per above, are also set to type string
```

Comment: I would suspect the culprit is `raw_data = Raw_data(**item)`. What is `Raw_data`, can you paste the source code?

Comment: @Lawrence I added the data model. Perhaps there is an issue with column types being set to string? Though I really wouldn't understand why that is....